# Buttons are not expanding to fill table cell

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4 and attempting to put buttons in a table cell for each row. But the buttons are not expanding to fill the area. They seem to be squished. When I shrink down to mobile, the same thing happens.

As you can see from the screenshot, the actions cell has plenty of space. But the buttons are malformed.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

[image]

```html
<table class="table table-striped small">
  <thead>
    <tr>

      <th>Status</th>
      <th class="d-none d-sm-table-cell">Tax ID</th>
      <th class="d-none d-sm-table-cell">Contractor ID</th>
      <th class="d-none d-sm-table-cell">Account</th>
      <th class="text-center">Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Unregistered</td>
      <td class="d-none d-sm-table-cell">123456789</td>
      <td class="d-none d-sm-table-cell">4113223</td>
      <td class="d-none d-sm-table-cell">N/A</td>
      <td class="text-center bg-danger">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-info  text-white"><i class="fas fa-vial d-none d-sm-none d-md-block"></i> <span class="d-none d-sm-none d-md-block">Create</span> Test Call</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-success   text-white"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt d-none d-sm-none d-md-block"></i> LogIn</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger  text-white"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt d-none d-sm-none d-md-block"></i> LogOut</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please post desired output as well. It's a little tricky to infer what you're looking to achieve from your question in its current form.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: `display: block`. Anchor elements are set to `inline` display by default.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements):

> A block-level element always starts on a new line and takes up the full width available (stretches out to the left and right as far as it can).

Answer (score 0):

try adding `btn-block` css class to each of your buttons.

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-block text-white"><i class="fas fa-vial d-none d-sm-none d-md-block"></i> <span class="d-none d-sm-none d-md-block">Create</span> Test Call</a>
```